# Git : get destination and source branche name during merge operation from client-side hook

Tags: git

I'm struggling to find how to limit the merge "direction" on some branches.
For example, imagine that we have `master`, `staging` and `development` branches in our repo :

- `master` should only accept to be fast-forwarded from `staging`
- `staging` should only accept to be fast-forwarded from `development`
- `development` should **not** be able to be merged directly to `master`

I know that we can achieve this logic using some server-side hooks such as `pre-receive`, but I don't have the ability to set my own server-side hooks.

Is there a way to get the destination branch name and the source branch name during a merge from a client-side hook to accept or block the merge operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a lot of things in client-side hooks, but you should be aware of several things before you even start down this path:

1. Anyone can simply turn off their hooks.  Only server-side hooks provide real enforcement.  Obviously, given your constraints, that's one of those cases of having to accept a half measure, since the full measure just isn't available.  But you should remember it.
2. Git doesn't really care about *branch names*.  Git cares about *commits*.  Branch names are just a way to *find* commits.  The names are entirely under the control of the user, so it's easy for someone to rename `master` to `hoopy`, `staging` to `frood`, and `development` to `towel`, after which any name-based checking is going to fail.  This particular example is contrived (and [meant to be amusing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towel_Day)), but this sort of thing *will* eventually happen to someone.  Be prepared for that.
3. There aren't enough Git hooks in enough positions to do the kinds of things you want done.  In particular, there is no "pre-merge" hook.  There is a pre-merge-commit hook, but that's a bit late at best (and completely skipped in some cases).

That last point is the one that will probably kill the idea of using *hooks* specifically, but you don't have to use a *hook* here.  **Just have people run your own command instead of running `git merge`.**  This can be an alias, or a little script you write, or whatever you like.

(Another way to do this is with a pre-push hook; here, you'll check to see if the *push request* would result in a state you don't like, and if so, reject the push request.  However, this happens pretty late, well after someone's done things that may be painful to undo or redo.  It also won't prevent someone from using a web button on GitHub for instance, but that's another topic entirely.)

Now, as to this part:

> Is there a way to get the destination branch name and the source branch name during a merge from a client-side hook to accept or block the merge operation?

You'll be requiring that people run your own command, rather than running `git merge`.  So you can simply require that the (single) argument be a branch name:

```
somescript <branchname>
```

That script will (or won't) run `git merge branchname`, after doing several checks.  The terms "destination branch" and "source branch" don't make sense to me, in that I don't know which one you mean by which of these phrases.  If and when you do invoke `git merge`, the merge command will use your *current branch*—the one you have checked out right now—as one of the two branch tips, and will use the argument you supply, i.e., the branch name, as the other of the two branch tips.

Remember that what `git merge` itself does is—to simplify it quite a lot—to find two *commits* that should be merged, if that's possible.  One of these is always the *current commit*.  The other is one you name.

To find the *current commit*, Git looks up the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this.<sup>1</sup>  That either resolves to a branch name, or directly to a commit hash ID.  If it resolves directly to a commit—when Git is in what it calls *detached HEAD* mode—Git is now done finding the current commit.  When it resolves to a branch name, as is the more normal everyday case, Git then looks up the branch name, which resolves to a commit hash ID.

To find the current *branch name*, Git looks up the special name `HEAD`.  Note that this is the same lookup as before!  However, having found whatever is inside the name `HEAD`—commit hash ID, or branch name—Git now checks to make sure it *is* a branch name.  If it's not, Git rejects this lookup as an error, saying that you are in detached HEAD mode and there is therefore no current branch name.  Otherwise, `HEAD` contains the branch name.  Git returns this branch name: that's the *current branch*.

Hence, the special name `HEAD` provides the answer to *both questions*.  You just have to ask Git the right question.  The way to ask Git *which branch name does `HEAD` represent?* is to use the `git symbolic-ref` command:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

Note that this produces the *full name* of the branch.  Branches have full names: you can use a branch's full name [when you're mad at it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1EbxYKh_4) or otherwise want to be *really sure* you get the right thing.  Or, you can use the shorter version, `master` or whatever, when you feel like using the shorter name—or when you *have* to, as in `git checkout` and `git switch`.  Git is not always very consistent.<sup>2</sup>  You can have `git symbolic-ref` print the short version with `--short`.

Anyway, you now have the name of the *current branch*.  The argument you're given is the name of the *other branch*.  Git will translate that argument to a commit hash ID, because `git merge` is about *commits*, and specifically, about combining work—except, that is, when it's about doing a *fast-forward*, which you also mentioned:

> `master` should only accept to be fast-forwarded from `staging`

Hence you'd want to detect whether the *current branch* is `master`, and if so, whether the argument is `staging`, and if so, whether this merge will be performed as a fast-forward, rather than as a real merge.

This is where we get into the complexity of merging.  But first, let's finish off some footnotes.

---

<sup>1</sup>Spelling this in lowercase, as `head`, or even weird mixed FunKY cAPitALizaTION, sometimes works.  It doesn't always work.  Don't do it!  If you hate typing out `HEAD` in all caps on the command line, consider using the `@` synonym.  In a script, you can use `@` or `HEAD` as you like; you won't have to retype it all the time so holding down shift, or using your editor to upcase the word `head`, or whatever, is probably not that painful.

If you're curious: it "works" when Git, not realizing that by `head` you meant `HEAD`-in-all-caps, feeds the name to the operating system.  This request causes the OS to look for a file named `head` in the `.git` directory holding the repository.  On some file systems, commonly on macOS and Windows for instance, this will find and open the file named `HEAD`.  That file contains the name of the current branch, so that everything Just Works.  It *fails* when you're on a system where case matters, so that trying to open `.git/head` *doesn't* open `.git/HEAD`, and also when you're in an added work-tree from `git worktree add`, where `.git/HEAD` gets you the branch name for the *main* work-tree.  The `HEAD` for this added work-tree is buried deep inside `.git/worktrees/`.  Git replaces the all-uppercase `HEAD` with the correct file name, but seeing `head`, thinks you aren't interested in `HEAD`, and *doesn't* do this replacement.

<sup>2</sup>This is not really one of the cases where Git is badly inconsistent: the full name stuff is about *references*, and when switching to a branch, we've already chosen to limit ourselves to *branch* references, rather than general references including tags and such.  But Git is notoriously organic, by which I mean in the ["just growed"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/29/messages/286.html), [messy evolutionary sense](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46306825_Messy_biology_and_the_origins_of_evolutionary_innovations).  There *is* a design, but stuck all over that design are ad-hoc solutions, leading to a system that is not always entirely logical.

---

#### How merge works

To understand how `git merge` works, you need to start with understanding the commit graph.  Rather than writing all of that here, let me just outsource this part to [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), or refer you to any of many of my other Git answers here on StackOverflow.

Now, suppose we have a graph fragment like this one:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here, we're indicating that the *current branch* is `branch1` and its tip commit is a commit whose hash ID we're just calling `J` for convenience.

If we now run `git merge branch2`, we get Git to look up the *name* `branch2` so as to find the *hash ID* of commit `L`.  You can do this yourself, using `git rev-parse`.  Remember that `git rev-parse` might *fail*, if given a bad branch name; you'll want to check for such things, in real code.  But for now we can do this:

```sh
hash=$(git rev-parse branch2)
```

in a shell script, to get the hash ID of commit `L`.  (We might like to get the hash ID of `HEAD`, perhaps, but we can just use the *name* `HEAD` directly.  This will only fail if we're on an *unborn branch*.)

Once Git has both hash IDs, Git needs to find the best *shared* (common) commit: a commit that's on *both branches*, from which Git can find changes to the two branch-tip commits `J` and `L` respectively.  To do that, `git merge` uses `git merge-base`, with the `--all` option:

```sh
bases=$(git merge-base --all HEAD $hash)
```

The merge-base program finds a, or all, merge base(s) of the given commits.  It exits zero (success) on finding and printing these.  It exits nonzero if there is no common ancestor.  So we should test for that:

```sh
bases=$(git merge-base --all HEAD $hash) || {
    echo "refusing to merge unrelated histories"
    exit 1
}
```

If there are multiple merge bases, we have a complex merge case.  There's no need to do anything special here: we can just let `git merge` handle it.  The cases we're concerned with, from this point on, are all simple single-merge-base cases.

If we were writing something fancier, we might want to check all of this explicitly.  But for our particular case here, we can simplify away the "multiple merge bases" case by just leaving out the `--all` option, rendering the above as:

```sh
base=$(git merge-base HEAD $hash) || {
    echo "refusing to merge unrelated histories"
    exit 1
}
```

If there *are* multiple merge bases, `git merge-base` will pick one of them at (apparent) random and we can just go on with the rest of our tests.  The randomly chosen single base will suffice for our tests here.  (Proving this is left as an exercise, should you wish to go on to turn this sketch into a full solution.  That, or you can assume that my intuition on this is correct: I haven't proven it myself!)

Now, for our example above, the `git merge-base` command will find the hash of commit `H`.  But there are other cases.  Suppose, for instance, that we have this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \
             J--K   <-- branch2
```

Here, the merge base of commits `I` and `K` is commit `I`.

Or, suppose we have this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch2
            \
             J--K   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
```

Here again, the merge base of commits `I` and `K` (or `K` and `I`—the order doesn't matter) is commit `I`.

Git will do a *real merge* in the first case, where the merge base was commit `H` and the two tip commits were `J` and `L` respectively.  That's because commit `H` is *behind* both branch tips.

In the end, we wind up with three cases:

- The merge base *is* the other commit: in this case, there is nothing to merge.  The `git merge` command will say "Already up to date" and just quit.
- The merge base is our *current commit:* in this case, the merge *can* be performed as a fast-forward.  For the special case current and other branches that you care about, you *want* a fast-forward, so you should run `git merge` and have it do that.
- The merge base is behind both the current and other commits: in this case, the merge requires a full merge.  For the special case current and other branches, you want to *forbid* this, so you should complain and abort the merge.

To check for these cases, we can compare `$base` against the hash ID of the current and other branches.  We have the hash ID of the other branch in `$hash`:

```sh
if [ $base == $hash ]; then
    echo "Already up to date."
    exit 0  # quit and do nothing
fi
```

Assuming this doesn't quit, we should go on to the rest of the tests.

To see if the hash ID of the base matches the hash ID of `HEAD`, we need to grab the hash ID of `HEAD`.  We can do this with `git rev-parse`:

```sh
headhash=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit # if rev-parse fails, quit
if [ $bash == $headhash ]; then
    ... is a fast forward ...
else
    ... is a real merge ...
fi
```

There are alternative tests you can use for many of these conditions.  For instance, `git merge-base --is-ancestor` will test two hash IDs to see if the first given hash ID is a predecessor of, or equal to, the second hash ID, in the partially ordered set determined by the commit graph.  That is:

```sh
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $h1 $h2; then ...; fi
```

is a way to test whether hash `$h1` precedes or equals hash `$h2`.

To build your "do a merge but only under the conditions we've decided are OK" script, then, you'll just need to string these various tests together in the right ways:

- Grab the current branch name, with `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.  If it fails (exits nonzero), there is no current branch (you are in detached HEAD) mode and you should have the script exit immediately.  Someone who really wants to run `git merge` in this state can just run `git merge` instead of your script.  Note that without any quiet flags, `git symbolic-ref HEAD` will itself print an error message for this detached-HEAD case, so you can just use `|| exit` in a shell script.
- Optionally, turn that into a hash ID right now with `git rev-parse`.  If that fails, exit now (`|| exit` as seen above several times).  This can only happen when on what Git calls an "unborn branch", in which case, merging will fail too.  Or, you can defer this until later, if and when you decide you need the hash ID of the current commit.
- Check the argument(s) to your script: verify that there is exactly one argument (using `$#` in a shell script), and that it *is* a valid name for a commit, using `git rev-parse`.  Then, if the *current branch* is one of the designated ones, determine:

  - whether the argument is also one of the designated ones
  - whether this means that the merge, if we proceed, must be a fast-forward, or must not be fast forward

  and use these to decide what's allowed.
- Check whether `git merge` would attempt a fast-forward, or a real merge.  Decide whether these are allowed, required, or forbidden based on the results of the earlier check.  Produce an appropriate error and exit for the error cases.
- Last, run `git merge` for the allowed cases.  (In a script like this, you might want to `exec git merge "$1"` or similar.)

Overall, this is probably a relatively simple shell script, just a few dozen lines at most.  The logic will be easy to modify, and if all else fails, anyone can just run `git merge` directly instead of this script.  All you're doing is providing a tool that checks for common mistakes, because that's all you *can* do here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, it was very instructive

Comment: Great answer! Just a question @torek: in the `pre-merge-commit` would you be able to retrieve the name of the second branch you are going to merge? Basically, what command reads the `MERGE_HEAD` file I found by chance in the `.git` folder.

Comment: The `git merge` command *writes* the MERGE_HEAD (and MERGE_MSG) files. These are breadcrumbs left behind in case the merge *fails* and merge has to stop and let you fix things up. At that point, the breadcrumb trail exists for whoever wants it: mostly prompt-setting in shells, and `git merge --continue` / `git commit` to finish up the merge. The problem with pre-merge-commit is that it doesn't get *run* when finishing a conflicted merge (this is documented, but seems to me to be a bug: on the other hand, being documented, it can't be fixed!).

Comment: @ArthurEudeline: By the way, when you want `git merge` to do a fast-forward, pass `--ff-only` as an option, otherwise someone who's configured their Git to do a real merge every time will get a real merge. See the `merge.ff` setting in `git config`.

Comment: @torek thanks for the hint, I was aware of the `--ff-only` but not for the `git config` setting

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because what you are asking is complex, at least given my knowledge on the git topic. Said that, my advice is to make those rules clear to anyone so that you will not have to implement very specific and hard-working checks.
Now, since you cannot use the `pre-receive` server-side hook, one possible client side hook you can use is [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push). The sample file that you can find by default in the `.git` folder is a good starting point, and even the documentation is well written.

I made many assumptions about your workflow to make the explanation more clear.
By the way, the only check you can do in this hook is whether the branches you are going to push are linear (at least for `master` and `staging`). You should replace the part in the sample about the check for the Work-In-Progress commit with this code (not exactly, but it contains the main logic):

```
cmt_counter=0
first_commit=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 master)
did_someone_merge=1

while [[ 0 != $(git rev-parse HEAD~${cmt_counter}^2 2> /dev/null > /dev/null || echo $?) ]]
do
    if [[ $(git rev-parse HEAD~${cmt_counter}) = "$first_commit" ]] 
    then
        did_someone_merge=0
        break
    fi

    cmt_counter=$((cmt_counter+1))
done

exit $did_someone_merge
```

It simply checks if every commit of the target branch (`master` in this case) has a single parent only. The advantage of looping over all the commits is that you make sure that no one rewrote the history or messed with it, partially.

Instead, about the third rule, I had a really ugly idea but I have not come up with anything better and still I am not sure it works everytime.
You could use the [`pre-merge-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) client-side hook to verify if the branches you are merging are "compatible". You could retrieve the current branch from `HEAD`, with some command like `git name-rev` and compare it with the branch whose tip is the one specified in the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.

There are certainly many other ways to do it (better than mine), I repeat: I would not do anything like what I have described because it takes time to do it well and this is not going to be stable, because of bugs or situation you have not considered, or just a change in your workflow. If you are still convinced that this is the right way, maybe a bounty will attract people more skilled than me.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer it’s very interesting! I’ce spent whole days to try to make something with hooks or GitLab CI but it is not very interesting way as it will run too often and this is still hard to get destination and source branch names... thanks for your precious advices anyway

Comment: You are welcome, with the `git merge-base` command described by @torek it is going to be much safer, I was probably tired of scripting and I did not want to write more :) His answer is gold.